# How to use extension method for ILoggerBuilder instead of ILoggerFactory?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53840298/5482465) but it is for asp.net core. My code below is for a **non-web** console app. Visual Studio tells me that `AddConsole(this ILoggerFactory,...)` is obsolete and must be replaced by `AddConsole(this ILoggingBuilder,...)`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ILoggerFactory ilf = new LoggerFactory();
        ilf.AddConsole(LogLevel.Information);

        ILogger<Program> logger = ilf.CreateLogger<Program>();

        logger.LogError("the cpu is overheating");

        Console.WriteLine("waiting for logger to print");
    }
}
```

## Question

How to use the extension method `AddConsole` for `ILoggingBuilder` instead of `ILoggerFactory` in the above case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling the `CreateDefaultBuilder()` method on `WebHost` like below. See this for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
    var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    logger.LogInformation("the cpu is overheating");
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
        });
```

If it's a console app, then probably you can just say

```
ILogger<Program> logger = new Logger<Program>(new LoggerFactory());
logger.LogError("System is over heated!!!");
```

That's not too difficult either, you need to extend `ILoggerProvider` and pass your custom provider to logger factory like

```
new LoggerFactory().AddProvider(new CustomProvider());
```

See this blog post with nice example for color console logging https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/05/05/add-custom-logging-in-aspnetcore.html

Comment: Your answer is for asp.net rather than for a non-web console app.

Comment: It does not show the error message on the console window.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest one is

```cs
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
```