# No overload for method "AddDebug" takes 1 arguments

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-3.1

I try to upgrade .net core sdk from 2.2 to 3.1 in my project.
In .net core sdk 2.2, I used `loggerFactory.AddDebug(Enum.Parse<LogLevel>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging:Debug:LogLevel:Default").Value));`  works fine. But in .net core sdk 3.1, I use same code, I getting "No overload for method "AddDebug" takes 1 arguments" error. I installed Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package v3.1.5 via nuget package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I getting "No overload for method "AddDebug" takes 1 arguments" error

If you check the definition of [`AddDebug()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.debugloggerfactoryextensions.adddebug?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_DebugLoggerFactoryExtensions_AddDebug_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggerFactory_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LogLevel_) in version 2.2 project, you would find the method is obsolete and the `AddDebug(this ILoggingBuilder builder)` is recommended alternative.

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Adds a debug logger that is enabled for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevels
    //     of minLevel or higher.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   factory:
    //     The extension method argument.
    //
    //   minLevel:
    //     The minimum Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel to be logged
    [Obsolete("This method is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative is AddDebug(this ILoggingBuilder builder).")]
    public static ILoggerFactory AddDebug(this ILoggerFactory factory, LogLevel minLevel);
```

And [above method has been removed from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.debugloggerfactoryextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) in version 3.0 and higher.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I got rid of this problem with the solution given in the link.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840298/how-to-fix-obsolete-iloggerfactory-methods).

Comment: The solution is same as I mentioned in above reply, using LoggingBuilder.AddDebug() is recommended alternative in 3.0+ project.