# EF Core Logging SQL Queries when Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, logging, nunit, ef-core-2.2

I'm running some unit tests (NUnit) on my `DbContext` (to an Oracle database) in EF Core 2.2 and I'd like to see the `SQL` queries it's constructing for each unit test, preferably

- in the Debug window *and*
- in the Test Explorer pane's detail view of each test.

I have a Unit Test similar to:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
        .UseOracle("some connection string")
        .Options;

    _context = new MyContext(options);
}
[Test]
public void We_can_count_all_the_things()
{
    var count = _context.Things.Count();

    Assert.That(count, Is.GreaterThan(0));

    // something like this for Test output:
    Assert.Pass($"SQL QUERY:{???}")
}
```

... or maybe I can use an `ILogger` to direct output to the test result or some magic I'm unaware of.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NUnit`'s [TestContext.WriteLine](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext#writeline) is what you are looking for:

```
...
TestContext.WriteLine($"SQL QUERY:{???}");
```

### **Edit:**

To get the generated SQL:

EF core:
[Get SQL code from an EF Core query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527783/get-sql-code-from-an-ef-core-query/44180537#44180537)

EF 6: [How do I view the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework/1412902#1412902)

Comment: That's half of half of the question - where can I get the SQL statement that was used?

Comment: @ScottBaker [How do I view the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412902/4332059) and [Get SQL code from an EF Core query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44180537/4332059)

Answer (score 2):

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51038026/1196867) that shows how to log EF Core SQL queries using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` package...

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory) // Warning: Do not create a new ILoggerFactory instance each time
        .UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFLogging;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
```

With something like this:-

```
public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = new LoggerFactory(new[] {new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true)});
```

Further info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging)

Comment: The argument to `new ConsoleLoggerProvider` now has type `IOptionsMonitor<ConsoleLoggerOptions>`, so that code does not compile. There is an explanation of how to create the object at https://mikehadlow.com/posts/standalone-consoleloggerprovider/, but after fixing the error and using code similar to that above (plus `optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()`), my unit tests still produce no output (neither in Test Explorer nor in the Output panel). The SQL only appears when running standalone in a console (via Main() => Startup).