# EF core error showing up randomly "The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 't'.\r\n"

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have this linq query which works perfectly fine but sometimes it throws exception, following is start :

`query = table.Include(x=>x.table2)`

after applying few conditions in code finally following is the line which throws exception :

`var data = await query.Skip(offset).Take(filter.PagingOption.PageSize).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();`

**ErrorDetail : 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 't'.\r\n**

Mostly it is observed that when IIS is restarted error occurs, but once the error is occurred on refresh this works totally fine. Which I guess is random behavior.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you make a reliable reproduction of it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893732/how-do-you-show-underlying-sql-query-in-ef-core-2-0? Maybe eg core team would fix it if it's a bug, or maybe try to repro it on efcore 3 and switch if it is immune?

Comment: Doesn't the exception include the full sql?

Comment: @CaiusJard reproduction is not easily possible as I to get this issue randomly

Comment: @JeremyLakeman exception includes very limited details here is the exception detail in case :
The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 't'.","ErrorDetail":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 't'.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task`1 result)\r\n 
  at

Comment: Is it related - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13922

Comment: If you set `.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)` the full sql and parameters of EF errors should be logged.