# How to view SQL generated by Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have couple of lines written like this:

```
 _DbContext.Business.Where(lb=>lb.id == (int)Constants.Business.Retail).Frist();
 
 //and 
 
_DbContext.Business.Where(lb=>lb.id == (int)Constants.Business.Retail).FristOrDefault();
```

How can I view SQL generated by this code during my debug (break point debug)?
The code suggested very lengthy. Any sample code for quick reference during debugging?
Thanks.

Comment: In what version of EF Core?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you show underlying SQL query in EF Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893732/how-do-you-show-underlying-sql-query-in-ef-core-2-0) or [Get SQL code from an Entity Framework Core IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527783/get-sql-code-from-an-entity-framework-core-iqueryablet)

Comment: The code suggested very lengthy. Any sample code for quick reference during debugging?

Comment: From EF properties; EF Run time version 4.0 and Version 6 with Visual Studio 2019