# Memory Leak with EF Core Logging

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, out-of-memory

I have a small Digital Ocean droplet (1GB of RAM) running the most current Ubuntu LTS. I created a small DotNet core 3.1 MVC web app (+ DotNet Core identity) that eventually hits a task limit and then throws (erroneous) OOM exceptions.

Representative Error messages from journalctl:

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13] Connection id "0HM1CRI33JJJE", Request id "0HM1CRI33JJJE:0000043E": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
 at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal()
 at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLoggerProvider..ctor(IOptionsMonitor`1 options)
 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
 at ... (etc)
```

Service status on fresh start:

```
Site.service - Description here
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Site.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-22 17:08:51 UTC; 48s ago
   Main PID: 656469 (Site)
      Tasks: 21 (limit: 1075)
     Memory: 103.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/Site.service
```

Status output with problem active:

```
 Site.service - Description here
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Site.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-22 17:08:51 UTC; 11min ago
   Main PID: 656469 (Site)
      Tasks: 1075 (limit: 1075)
     Memory: 176.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/Site.service
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? What version of .NET Core is this? Can you share how you are building/publishing/deploying it? How are you configuring the service? Can you reproduce this issue with a Hello MVC Web application? Can you reproduce the problem if you remove the Identify stack from your application? What does the initial memory use look like? Does the application reach some sort of steady state of memory use after a few hours of running before it crashes? Can you grab a heap dump of the appliation, hopefully, just a little before the crash?

Comment: I haven't reproduced with Hello World or w/o the Identity Stack. I'm not sure I want to invest the time in that sort of thing until other items have been ruled out...

I updated the main post with answers to most of your questions. I don't know how to grab a heap dump, but if you tell me I'll do it.

Note that the app doesn't really crash; it appears to still be running, it just throws an OOM exception with each new request.

I noticed the service status output lists Tasks, and it is essentially at the limit. Is that expected?

Comment: @omajid I have narrowed down to what is causing the issue (not OOM after all -- it's out of tasks).

Comment: ....and figured it out. Bad logging configuration was causing a memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in the [EF Core logging documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3#other-applications), a memory leak can be introduced if a new logging factory is created for each context.

Bad code:

```
options.UseSqlite(SqliteDbContext.DataSource)
    .UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(x => x.AddConsole())); // log SQL to console
```

Correct code:

```
options.UseSqlite(SqliteDbContext.DataSource)
    .UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory) // _loggerFactory is now a static property
```

<sub>*Added on behalf of the question author.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3

```
public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
= LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddConsole(); });

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
=> optionsBuilder
    .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
    .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFLogging;ConnectRetryCount=0");
```

Comment: could you please explain the answer. if you are sharing a post please use it as a reference not as an answer.