# How to view raw query which generated by LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to see the generated sql to debug with Console.WriteLine();
In Visual studio Code, with Console.WriteLine(), I can't see the raw query;

```
    var result = from employee in db.EmployeeUsers
                        ...
             select employee.id..;
     string sql = result.ToString();

 Console.WriteLine(sql);
```

But it show like this

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1641]
```

How I can see raw query like this?

```
[SELECT employee.id FROM ... WHERE...;]
```

---

I set this first,

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
     ,"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"
    }
  },
```

But I didn't see if I set it up wrong.
And then I set

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
```

But it shows every Raw Query.

I simply want Query to be printed only on the part I designated in Visual Studio Code Terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you show underlying SQL query in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893732/how-do-you-show-underlying-sql-query-in-ef-core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can call .ToQueryString() or use the Query property.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68797954/1974021

```
var result = from employee in db.EmployeeUsers
                    ...
         select employee.id..;
string sql = result.ToQueryString();
```

Comment: Please mark duplicate questions as duplicate instead of providing the same answer as has already been given.