# LInq to query - search functionality

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this following code in my repository layer, This code basically gets the string and returns the list of objects containing the string in an email field.

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<UserTable>> GetUsers(string userSearch)
        {
            var item = await riskDBContext.UserTables.Where(e=>e.Email.Contains(userSearch)).ToListAsync(); ;
            return item;
        }
```

The User table contains like 50000 records. If the column email is indexed will this search translate faster in the SQL query?

Please note email is not the primary key. Basically I am implementing the auto-search functionality and when the user types in 3 characters or more it starts calling this function.

Since I am using Linq, I assume the following function will translate into the equivalent query.

```
select * from usertable where email like '%userSearch%'
```

Apart from indexing the email column should I be doing anything else?
is this the right way to do for querying?

Comment: Tip: you can check the logs to find the generated SQL query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66662556/10839134

Answer (score 0):

> If the column email is indexed will this search translate faster in the SQL query?

No, index will be used only if you use `StartsWith`

```cs
e.Email.StartsWith(userSearch)
```

For better performance you can use [FreeText Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/freetexttable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [how to use it](https://www.bricelam.net/2020/08/08/mssql-freetext-and-efcore.html) with EF Core

Or install somewhere [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) server, synchronise with SQL Server data and use it for fast and rich search capabilities.

Comment: What is elastic search and where to install it?

Comment: even if I use freetext, how should I write the LINQ then?