# Why linq contains always returning false value when combined with empty and non empty strings?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, contains

Details:

1. In this below code `_reportData.DistrictID` and `reportData.BeneficieryID` values are `""`. But filter condition is not working. My requirement is to get matching values from the table.
2. Below code is not filtering the data.

Below is the code to retrieve filtered data

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<BeneficieryMasterExcelUpload>> GetBeneficieryReports(ReportsDataSearch _reportData)
    {
       

        IEnumerable<BeneficieryMasterExcelUpload> beneficieryList = _appDBContext.BeneficieryMasterExcelUpload;
        try
        {

            var beneficieryList = (from b in _appDBContext.BeneficieryMasterExcelUpload
                                   where b.Financial_Year.Contains(_reportData.FinancialYear)
                                   || b.District.Contains(_reportData.DistrictID) ||
                                   b.Name.Contains(_reportData.BeneficieryID) ||
                                   b.District.Contains(_reportData.DistrictID) ||
                                   b.Taluk.Contains(_reportData.TalukID) ||
                                          b.Village.StartsWith(_reportData.VillageID) ||
                                           b.SchemeName.Contains(_reportData.SchemeMasterID)



                                   select new BeneficieryMasterExcelUpload()
                                   {
                                       BeneficieryID = b.BeneficieryID,
                                       Name = b.Name,
                                       SchemeName = b.SchemeName,
                                       BusinessName = b.BusinessName,
                                       District = b.District,
                                       Taluk = b.Taluk,
                                       Village = b.Village,
                                       Constitunency_num = b.Constitunency_num,
                                       BankName = b.BankName,
                                       Financial_Year = b.Financial_Year,
                                       Religion = b.Religion,

                                   }).ToList();
            return beneficieryList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the generated SQL? What database are you running this against?

Comment: No .Please guide me how to check it

Comment: There are multiple answers how to do that - [here is one for EF 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61204960/2501279) .

Comment: you can get query with sql profiler .please share your model and example data to test code?

Comment: try executing raw sql instead like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries
also make sure you are indexing your database properly, because this query looks very unhealthy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to filter the `Beneficiery` with the `BeneficieryID`?

I observed that one of the line says `b.Name.Contains(_reportData.BeneficieryID)`. Instead, are you trying to refer to
`b.Beneficiery.Contains(_reportData.BeneficieryID)`?