Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AspNetRole'.'
I have a table named AspNetRoles in my database and context generated from the database.
I get the error when trying to query AspNetRoles from the table via context. It probably thinks the table name is singular and not able to find a table named AspNetRole. Now, the question is how to address the right table?
The AspNetRole entity:
[Table("AspNetRoles")]
public partial class AspNetRole
{
    public AspNetRole()
    {
        TenantRoles = new HashSet<TenantRole>();
        Users = new HashSet<AspNetUser>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedName { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TenantRole> TenantRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> Users { get; set; }
}

OneModelCreating:
modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRole>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(128);

    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(256);

    entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedName).HasMaxLength(256);
});

Context:
public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }

The error I get:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AspNetRole'.'

I am trying to query AspNetRoles from the AspNetRoles table in database. I am expecting to find a way to make my context reach the right table when querying.

Remove images and post code. SO has rich Markdown support.

Maybe you are missing a migration or Update-Database ?

I should not create migration and update the database, it is database first. Actually I did create a migration on my local and it created the table as AspNetRole, I want to address AspNetRoles, it should create AspNetRoles not Role. How to make it to create AspNetRoles when creating migration.

Have you tried enabling SQL logging in your application? Seeing the SQL that causes the issue might steer you in the right direction.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893732/how-do-you-show-underlying-sql-query-in-ef-core

looks like EF is looking for the table named AspNetRole rather than AspNetRoles. first check your connection string is pointing to the correct database and check table name in database. In your OnModelCreating method in the DbContext class, try to configure the mapping using Fluent API to ensure Entity Framework Core recognizes the correct table. try to use var roles = context.AspNetRoles.ToList(); in DbContext to query table so that it will point to the correct table

I have already tried all these, but nothing has changed. Just [Table("AspNetRoles", Schema="dbo")] caused the error to change as 'Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetRole'.'

I am logged in to the SQL Server, I see the db and I know what the problem is; EF tries to reach a table that does not exist ('AspNetRole'), it is 'AspNetRoles' in the db and I am trying to make EF to reach 'AspNetRoles' instead of 'AspNetRole'. And I don't understand why EF is trying to reach the table that does not exist, the context is generated using the 'Scaffold' command and it should have generated all correctly. The 'AspNetRoles' is generated in the context, which means EF reached the db and saw that table and generated but when querying it does not recognize it.

Try to configure  explicitly table name in the OnModelCreating method modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRole>(entity => { entity.ToTable("AspNetRoles");   entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(128);. run your application again after making this change to verify that EF correctly queries the "AspNetRoles" table.
